# Kinetic.js: Get MinX, MaxX, MinY, and MaxY of rotated Kinetic.Label

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to prevent a rotated Label from being dragged off the screen, but I cannot figure out how to get MinX, MaxX, MinY, and MaxY of the object ***in its rotated state***. getHeight & getWidth only return the values prior to the rotation.

Here is an example illustrating the problem:

```
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
     container: 'container',
     width: window.innerWidth,
     height: window.innerHeight
 });

 var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

 var labelLeft = new Kinetic.Label({
     x: 95,
     y: 180,
     opacity: 1.0,
     listening: true,
     draggable: true,
     rotationDeg: -45,
     text: {
         text: 'Pointing Arrow',
         fontFamily: 'Calibri',
         fontSize: 20,
         padding: 5,
         fill: 'white'
     },
     rect: {
         fill: 'blue',
         pointerDirection: 'left',
         pointerWidth: 20,
         pointerHeight: 38,
         stroke: 'black',
         strokeWidth: 2
     },
     dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
         var newY = pos.y < 50 ? 50 : pos.y;
         return {
             x: pos.x,
             y: newY
         };
     }
 });

 layer.add(labelLeft);

 // add the layer to the stage
 stage.add(layer);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fSNnA/4/

In this example, I use dragBoundFunc to prevent the label from being dragged above y=50. but since the label is rotated, its actual highest point (MinY) has changed, and therefore you can drag it up and partially out of view.

What I really need is a function that will return the absolute current MinX, MaxX, MinY, and MaxY - taking into account the angle of rotation and length of text will not always be the same.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to calculate the bounding-box size of a rotated rectangle (label).

```
var w =    label.getWidth();
var h =    label.getHeight();
var rads = label.getRotation();
var c =    Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
var s =    Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
var newWidth =  h * s + w * c;
var newHeight = h * c + w * s;
```

Then assuming you'll always rotate around the center, the left/top boundaries are:

```
var centerX = label.getX()+label.getWidth()/2;
var centerY = label.getY()+label.getHeight()/2;

var MinX = centerX - newWidth/2;
var MinY = centerY - newHeight/2;
```

*[ Disclaimer:  This is just off the top of my head--review it accordingly! ]*

Comment: Thanks!

I used setOffset() to move the rotation point to the center of the label, and the only thing I had to change in your code was:

    var centerX = pos.x + this.getOffsetX();
    var centerY = pos.y + this.getOffsetY();

Thanks again, it worked great.